# Load data via SQL * Loader in IDENTITY column in Oracle 12c

Tags: sql, oracle, identity, sql-loader

I need to load data using SQL* Loader into Oracle table with GENERATE ALWAYS AS IDENTITY

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_identity
(
  col1 NUMBER(10,0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY(START WITH 7 INCREMENT BY 1)    NOT NULL,
  col2 VARCHAR2(20)
);
```

But when I try to load data in this table, I get an error

```
ORA-32795: cannot insert into a generated always identity column
```

Maybe there are any option in SQLLDR which skip IDENTITY for a while?

Or maybe there are any ideas how I can load data into GENERATED ALWAYS IDENTITY column using SQLLDR?

SQLLDR command

```
sqlldr userid=user/passw@TNS control=tbl_identity.ctl log=tbl_identity.log rows=1000 readsize=65535 bindsize=65535
```

CTL-file

```
OPTIONS(direct=false)
LOAD DATA
INFILE 'tbl_identity.txt'
INTO TABLE tbl_identity
INSERT
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' TRAILING NULLCOLS
(col1,
 col2)
```

Comment: ignore that column and load the others. can you show the sql loader script?

Comment: But if I have something like this

`1 'one'`
`2 'two'`
`4 'four'`

And If I ignore 1st column, it will load me incorrect data

Here is SQLLDR command

   `sqlldr userid=user/passw@TNS control=tbl_identity.ctl log=tbl_identity.log rows=1000 readsize=65535 bindsize=65535`

Comment: I think you should post the content of tbl_identity.ctl

Comment: OPTIONS(direct=false)
LOAD DATA
INFILE 'tbl_identity.txt'
INTO TABLE tbl_identity
INSERT
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' TRAILING NULLCOLS
(col1,
 col2)

Answer (score 1):

Change your DDL from `GENERATED ALWAYS` to `GENERATED BY DEFAULT`

Comment: Ok, I've already thought about this solution but I want to prevent any INSERTs into IDENTITY column after loading data into table. I've tried to make `ALTER TABLE  MODIFY col1  NUMBER(10,0)  GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY` but in that case I need to specify START position for identity - MAX (col1) +1. And if I have a lot of tables, I'm wondering how I can do it quickly

Comment: This is not really a viable solution. There is a clear difference in intent when using the two parameters in the DDL. I'm a bit surprised that GENERATED ALWAYS behaves this way. Is there no means to combine it with SQL * Loader?

Answer (score 0):

I use the following script before loading the data :

```
begin
  for rec in (
    select owner, table_name, column_name, generation_type
    from all_tab_identity_cols
    where owner = 'owner '
      and generation_type in ('ALWAYS')
      and table_name in ('','',......)
  )loop
     -- before load data
     if rec.generation_type = 'ALWAYS' then
       execute immediate 'alter table '||rec.owner||'.'||rec.table_name||' modify '||rec.column_name||' generated by default as identity';
     end if;
     if rec.generation_type = 'BY DEFAULT' then
     -- return (after data load)
       execute immediate 'alter table '||rec.owner||'.'||rec.table_name||' modify '||rec.column_name||' generated always as identity';
     end if;
  end loop;
end;            
/
```

and then return everything to the way it was.

**Be careful, list the right tables in the query!**